# Pre Build Event: Copy Folder and it's SubFolders and files into Build Directory using XCopy

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have Window Application and I have some plugins & it's ChildPlugins which I placed in  My Application folder structure(see folder structure image). I used SVN as source control so, every folder has `.SVN` folder.

Here is My Question:

Below image is my directory structure for Plugins. All folder have some files related it plugins. Now I want to copy all folder (with SubFolders) &  it's files to my Application  Build output path by using Pre Built Event.

[image: **Plugins Directory structure**]

After searching on net I found that by using XCopy I can achieve what I want. By using below code I can copy Plugins directory & it's files but can't able to copy it's sub folders & Sub folder Files .

```
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)Plugins\*.*" "$(SolutionDir)Windows\Host\Host.GUI\bin\x86\$(ConfigurationName)\Plugins\" /Y/D
```

I want to copy Folder & it's all subfolders with all files and want to exclude `.SVN`. Can anyone point me How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: As @CrazyCasta's answer after adding /E in my code It's working perfectly. xcopy "$(SolutionDir)Plugins\*.*" "$(SolutionDir)Windows\Host\Host.GUI\bin\x86\$(ConfigurationName)\Plugins\" /Y/D/E

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add the /E switch to copy subdirectories (including Empty ones).

Answer (score 33):

I have used this:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)MyFolder\*.*" "$(SolutionDir)ConsoleApplication1\bin\Release\MyFolder" /Y /I /E
```

And worked fine, the folder 'MyFolder' appear into my 'Release' folder when I compile the project with all the documents in it.

Something to point out here is that the path that is after $(SolutionDir) would change depending of the name of your solution, my solution is ConsoleApplication1.

Answer (score 18):

Better if it doesn't require a path with solution name or configuration type:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)MyFolder\*.*" "$(TargetDir)\MyFolder" /Y /I /E
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of copying Assets folder (located in the project folder) into bin(debug or release ...)\Assets

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(ProjectDir)Assets\*.*&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Configuration)\Assets&quot; /Y /I /E" />
</Target>
```

*Note, double quotes are replaced with a special word*